# Create hyperlink in email in Zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, model-view-controller, zend-framework2

I have developing an application with the use of the MVC architecure in Zend Framework 2.

I have an email which is sent to administrators, and now require to attach a hyperlink which will have the basepath included in it.

All my business logic is handled in the service layer which does not make use of the viewhelper.

Is there any suggested solution for this?

Comment: SO is not the right place to seek architecture/technical design ideas. The most value of posting a question here comes when you present actual solution(s) that is(are) giving you actual headaches.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am asking ho to grab $this->basepath() from within the service layer?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should be injecting a dependency from your controller into your service object.  Working backwards like that is not good practice.  Since you mentioned that you're leveraging MVC, I imagine that this is a Controller action and not a CLI command?  So do it like this:

**Controller**

```
use \Application\Service\Bar;

public function fooAction(){

    $bar_with_basepath = $this->getServiceLocator()->get( Bar::class, ['basepath' => $this->basePath() ] );
    $bar_with_basepath->execute();

}
```

Next, link your service to a factory

**Config**

```
use \Application\Service\Bar;
use \Application\Factory\Service\BarFactory;

...

'service_manager' => [

    'factories' => [
         Bar::class => BarFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

Then, define your factory code to include MutableCreationOptions

**Factory**

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\MutableCreationOptionsInterface;

class BarFactory implements FactoryInterface, MutableCreationOptionsInterface{

    protected $options;

    public function setCreationOptions( array $options )
    {
        $this->options = $options;
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {

        $serviceManager = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();


        $bar = new Bar( $this->options['basepath'] );
        return $bar;
    }
}
```

Now, you have the guarantee that the base path will be passed to your Bar service's constructor.

```
class Bar {

     public $basepath;

     public function __construct( $basepath ){
         $this->basepath = $basepath;
     }

     public function execute(){
         // do something with the basepath
     }


}
```

You'll need to handle getting any other dependencies into your service (Bar above) from your Factory.  For example, setting the service locator and such (which is very easy now, with ServiceLocatorAwareTrait).

Always inject your dependencies, don't try to reverse engineer them :)